Wordpress add_filter page_link returns 404
I'm trying to change the permalink from page which has parent the front page!
Please do not ask "why?". The customer wants to have few pages as children of front page to find them easily. I suggested him other ways but he doesn't want.
Here is my code
add_filter( 'page_link', 'remove_parent_front_page_link', 10, 3 );
function remove_parent_front_page_link( $permalink, $post ) {
    $parent_id = get_post_field( 'post_parent', $post);
    $front_page_id = get_option('page_on_front');

    if ( $parent_id ==  $front_page_id) {
        $front_page_slug = get_post_field( 'post_name', $parent_id);
        $permalink = str_replace( '/'.$front_page_slug, '', $permalink );
    }

    return $permalink;
}

The permalink changed on dashboad, but when i click to check it, returns 404.
I re-save the permalinks manually from Settings->Permalinks->Save Changes

This only changes links to those pages, it doesn't tell WordPress what content to use when those pages are accessed. You'll need to add custom rewrite rules to support this.
